# Searches with :g not working with PyCharm IdeaVIM plugin

Tags: vim, pycharm, ideavim

Trying to delete all lines containing `HAVING` in a query that I'm writing using global search and it's not working.

Tried both commenting and deleting.

```
query text
HAVING value > 200
query text
```

Search examples:

```
:g/HAVING/d

:g/HAVING/s/^/--/g
```

After entering the command I get the following messages:
`VIM - Not an editor command: g|g/HAVING/d`
and
`VIM - Not an editor command: g|g/HAVING/s/^/--/g`

Version PyCharm 2020.1.2
Build Number: PC-201.7846.77
IdeaVim Version: 0.59

Note that I've successfully tested both of these commands in `VIM` in the terminal. Both work work in PyCharm if I don't specify the `g` (but it only does one line at a time), e.g. the following works for one line at a time:
`:/HAVING/d`

Comment: Maybe it doesn't have the short version of `:global` or `:delete`? Does `:global/HAVING/delete` work? Just a wild guess.

Comment: What you have in PyCharm is a Vim *emulator*, not Vim, so you shouldn't expect *anything* to work in it as it works in Vim. If you feel something is missing or broken, use one of [the plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim)'s dedicated support channels.

Comment: @JakeGrossman I did try `global/delete` (should have specified) but thank you for the suggestion, regardless! 
@romainl thanks for the heads-up; will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:global` and `:vglobal` commands aren't supported by IdeaVim at the moment. However, this is one of the top voted issues, so it should be implemented soon. Here is the ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-831